# button onclick not triggered when clicking on a button created in asp.net (changed the div.innerhtml with a html string)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, button

So, basically the question is in the title,

I have a div (loginP within loginDiv) for loging in.
after the user logs in, the innerHtml of loginP changes via Asp.net.
I also use jquery to let the user of the site move the loginDiv (that contains the loginP) up and down, maybe that matters.

here is the normal html part of the code:

```
<div id="loginDiv" runat="server">
        <div id="loginP" runat="server">
            username:<br />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="user" Rows="1" class="textboxL" /><br />
            password:<br />
            <asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" runat="server" ID="pass" Rows="1" class="textboxL" /><br />
            <div id="bottomDiv">
                <asp:Button ID="RegiButton" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="buttonC"
                    Text="Register" OnClick="RegisterBtnClick" />
                <asp:Button ID="LogButton" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="true" CssClass="buttonC"
                    Text="Login" OnClick="LoginBtnClick" /><br />
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="rememberME" />
                <p id="rememberMe">
                    <font size="1" face="verdana">remember me</font>
                </p>
                <asp:Label Width="180px" Height="40px" Visible="true" runat="server" Text="" ID="errorLabel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the jquery part

```
    var ldiv = $("#loginDiv");
ldiv.offset({ top: 10 });


var drag = { y: 0, state: false };
var delta = { y: 0 };


$("#user").mousedown(function () {
    drag.state = false;
    $("#user").focus()
});
$("#pass").mousedown(function () {
    drag.state = false;
    $("#pass").focus()
});
//$("#LogOutBtn").mousedown(function () {
//    drag.state = false;
//    return false;
//});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LogOutBtn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sMaster.Master/LogoutBtnClick",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
        });
    });
});



ldiv.mousedown(function (e) {
    if (!drag.state == true) {
        drag.y = e.pageY;
        drag.state = true;
    }
    return false;
});

$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    if (drag.state == true) {
        delta.y = e.pageY - drag.y;
        var cur_offset = $("#loginDiv").offset();

        if (ldiv.cssNumber("top") + $("#loginP").cssNumber("padding-top") + delta.y > -40 && ldiv.cssNumber("top") + $("#loginP").cssNumber("padding-top") + $("#loginP").cssNumber("height") + delta.y + 60 < $(window).height()) {
            if ($(window).width() >= 1305) {
                $("#loginDiv").offset({ top: (cur_offset.top + delta.y) });
                drag.y = e.pageY;
            }
        }

    }
});

$(document).mouseup(function () {
    drag.state = false;
});


$("#user").mousedown(function () {
    drag.state = false;
    $("#user").focus()
});
$("#pass").mousedown(function () {
    drag.state = false;
    $("#pass").focus()
});
```

and there is also this part of the jQuery code that moves the loginDiv when the window is too small:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var dLeft = $("#greenPart").width();
    dLeft += ($(window).width() - $("#greenPart").width()) / 2;
    dLeft += 10;
    $("#loginDiv").css("marginLeft", dLeft);

    var he = $(window).height() * 2;
    $("#loginDiv").css({ "height": he + "px" });
    he = -($(window).height());
    $("#loginDiv").css({ "top": he + "px" });
    he = $(window).height();
    $("#loginP").css({ "padding-top": he + "px" });

    if ($(window).width() < 1305) {
        $("#loginDiv").offset({ top: 10 });
        $("#loginDiv").css({ "height": 120 + "px" });
        $("#loginP").css({ "padding-top": 0 + "px" });
        var dLeft = $("#greenPart").width();
        dLeft += ($(window).width() - $("#greenPart").width()) / 2;
        dLeft -= (20 + $("#loginP").width());
        $("#loginDiv").css("marginLeft", dLeft - 100);

        $("#lines").height("20px");
        $("#lines").width("100px");
        $("#bottomDiv").css("marginLeft", 165);
        $("#bottomDiv").css("marginTop", -90);
        $("#bottomDiv").css("width", 70);
        $("#hello").css("font-weight", "bold");
        $("#hello").css("color", "White");
    }

    return false;
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    var dLeft = $("#greenPart").width();
    dLeft += ($(window).width() - $("#greenPart").width()) / 2;
    dLeft += 10;
    $("#loginDiv").css("marginLeft", dLeft);

    var he = $(window).height() * 2;
    $("#loginDiv").css({ "height": he + "px" });
    he = -($(window).height());
    $("#loginDiv").css({ "top": he + "px" });
    he = $(window).height();
    $("#loginP").css({ "padding-top": he + "px" });

    $("#bottomDiv").css("marginLeft", 0);
    $("#bottomDiv").css("marginTop", 0);
    $("#bottomDiv").css("width", 170);
    $("#hello").css("font-weight", "normal");
    $("#hello").css("color", "Black");
    $("#loginP").css("padding-left", 0);

    if ($(window).width() < 1305) {
        $("#loginDiv").offset({ top: 10 });
        $("#loginDiv").css({ "height": 120 + "px" });
        $("#loginP").css({ "padding-top": 0 + "px" });
        var dLeft = $("#greenPart").width();
        dLeft += ($(window).width() - $("#greenPart").width()) / 2;
        dLeft -= (20 + $("#loginP").width());
        $("#loginDiv").css("marginLeft", dLeft - 100);

        $("#lines").height("20px");
        $("#lines").width("100px");
        $("#bottomDiv").css("marginLeft", 165);
        $("#bottomDiv").css("marginTop", -90);
        $("#bottomDiv").css("width", 70);
        $("#loginDiv").css("paddingLeft", 0);

        if ($("#hello").length != 0) {
            $("#hello").css("font-weight", "bold");
            $("#hello").css("color", "White");
            $("#loginP").css("padding-left", 120);
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

and the Asp.net part, the changeLoginDiv() changes the div and creates the problem:

```
 protected void LoginBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = user.Text;
        string password = pass.Text;

        if (username != "" && username != null)
        {
            if (password != "" && password != null)
            {
                if (db.IsExist("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + username + "'"))
                {
                    if (db.IsExist("SELECT * FROM users WHERE [password]='" + password + "'"))
                    {
                        errorLabel.Text = "Loged in successfully.";

                        if (rememberME.Checked == true)
                        {
                            Response.Cookies["userInfo"]["username"] = username;
                            Response.Cookies["userInfo"]["lastVisit"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                            Response.Cookies["userInfo"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Session["username"] = username;
                        }

                        changeLoginDiv();
                    }
                    else errorLabel.Text = "Wrong password.";
                }
                else errorLabel.Text = "The username doesn't exist. \n\n\nIf you don't have a user, please register.";
            }
            else errorLabel.Text = "Please enter a password";
        }
        else errorLabel.Text = "Please enter a user name";
    }

    protected void LogoutBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["username"] = "";
        Response.Cookies["userifnfo"]["username"] = "";

        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
    protected void MyProfileBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    public void changeLoginDiv()
    {
        string sessionST = (string)Session["username"];
        string cookiesST = (string)Request.Cookies["userifnfo"]["username"];
        if ((sessionST != null && sessionST != ""))
        {
            //loginP changes;

            string newHTML = "<span id='hello' height='22px'> Hello " + sessionST + "<br />";
            newHTML += "<img id='lines' src='images/lines.png' /></span>";
            newHTML += "<span><input type='button' id='ProfileBtn' height='30px' width='40px' runat='server' class='buttonC' value='My Profile' onclick='MyProfileBtnClick' /><br />";
            newHTML += "<input type='button' id='LogOutBtn' height='30px' width='40px' runat='server' Class='buttonC' value='Logout' onclick='LogoutBtnClick' /></span>";
            //newHTML += "<asp:Button ID='LogOutBtn' Height='22px' Width='50px' runat='server' UseSubmitBehavior='false' CssClass='buttonC' Text='Logout' OnClick='LogoutBtnClick' /></span>";


            loginP.InnerHtml = newHTML;
            loginP.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: center;");
        }
        if ((cookiesST != null && cookiesST != ""))
        {
            //loginP changes;

            string newHTML = "<span height='22px'> Hello " + cookiesST + "<br />";
            newHTML += "<img id='lines' src='images/lines.png' /></span>";
            newHTML += "<span><input type='button' id='ProfileBtn' height='30px' width='40px' runat='server' class='buttonC' value='My Profile' onclick='MyProfileBtnClick' /><br />";
            newHTML += "<input type='button' id='LogOutBtn' height='30px' width='40px' runat='server' Class='buttonC' value='Logout' onclick='LogoutBtnClick' /></span>";

            loginP.InnerHtml = newHTML;
            loginP.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: center;");
        }
    }
```

thanks =]

PS. as you can see i also tried to use trigger the onclick event in jQuery with ajax and some other function:

```
//$("#LogOutBtn").mousedown(function () {
//    drag.state = false;
//    return false;
//});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LogOutBtn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sMaster.Master/LogoutBtnClick",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: why is there no dom object with the id LogOutBtn in your markup?

Comment: Also, is your markup inside an UpdatePanel? When you click the button is a post back occurring but the function isn't firing?

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson
there is no UpdatePanel and acually i haven't ever heard of it..
how can i check if the code gets to the ajax part..? all i know is that it never gets to the LogoutBtnClick function in the asp.net, cause i inserted a breakpoint there (and, well, nothing happens)

Comment: You haven't posted any code or markup pointing to a LogoutBtnClick function.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson
i have, it's in the asp.net part

Comment: It's not being assigned to a button anywhere that I can see in the markup or code-behind.

Comment: Can I just double check something, does any of your selectors work? I ask becasue you're using the id specificed in the codebehind, which (depending on your markup) may differ when it's served to the client.